# Type definition for dimensions

Tags: haskell

How would one define a type for dimensions?

Can you define a type in terms of another type? (i.e. an inch is 72 PostScript points).
Would it even make sense to make a new type for a dimension unit?

I've seen libraries for other kind of units, but the dimensions I'd be interested in are:
scaled point (smallest, maybe Int?), point (65536 scaled points), pica (12 points), etc.

Comment: Aren't those units of measurement, not dimensions?

Comment: @delnan: I was going by the terms used by TeX. My dictionary says: "Dimension: a measurable extent of some kind, such as length, breadth, depth, or height"

Comment: "Dimension" seems a suitable term for this question. While I came here expecting to see a different meaning of the word (i.e. axis) I find the intended meaning both plain and natural.

Comment: Note - some units you might think you want (Em, En) are not scalar values, instead they are contextual on the "current point size".

Comment: @stephen tetley: You could define "em" and "en" as dimensionless multipliers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is where [phantom type](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type)s can help.  The [dimensional package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional) is a good place to start to understand them.  The code is literate Haskell and very readable so I'd recommend reading through that.

Comment: +1 for the dimensional package, which does exactly what the question asks for.